# Finding the minimum distance from the origin to the surface $xyz^2=2$

Tags: optimization, proof-verification, lagrange-multiplier

This was an old exam question I was looking at for a friend, although it's been a while since I've done this stuff:

**Q.** Find the shortest distance from the origin to the surface $xyz^2=2$.

I remembered Lagrange Multipliers being used in that course, so I did the following.

Define $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, which is what we want to minimize, with the constraint $g(x,y,z)=xyz^2=2$.

We get three equations (I'm using $f$ as shorthand to avoid the messy root):

1. $\frac{x}{f}=\lambda yz^2$ or $\frac{x^2}{f}=2\lambda$
2. $\frac{y}{f}=\lambda xz^2$ or $\frac{y^2}{f}=2\lambda$
3. $\frac{z}{f}=2\lambda xyz$ or $\frac{z^2}{f}=4\lambda$

We get $y=\pm x$, $z=\pm \sqrt{2} \cdot x$ and with the constraint only $y=x$ will work.

Finally we get $x=\pm 1$ and this gives us $4$ points $\pm(1,1,\sqrt2)$ and $\pm(1,1,-\sqrt2)$.

I haven't really used $\lambda$ though... so it's like I didn't really do it properly.

Comment: As a general note, it is often easier computationally to minimize $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ rather than $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ - it yields the same answer as well.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life that actually makes sense. I wouldn't have thought of it. Thank you.

Comment: It's smart to eliminate $\lambda$ in the first step and forget about it. You don't need $\lambda$, so there's no reason to calculate it.

Comment: @IlikeSerena Yeh I was thinking that it didn't seem to play a role in this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one can be zero. So, in that surface, $z^2=2/xy$. Now, by AM-GM

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2+y^2+\frac{2}{xy}\geq2xy +\frac{2}{xy}\geq 2\sqrt{4}=4.$$ Study the conditions for the equality to happen and show that they actually happen for the points you already suspect.

Comment: Actually I jumped ahead of myself, just the last inequality?

Comment: @snulty, $$2xy+\frac{2}{xy}\geq 2\sqrt{2xy\cdot\frac{2}{xy}}=2\sqrt 4=4.$$

Comment: I didn't realise you were using it twice.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Use $\ds{\tt\mbox{Spherical Coordinates}}$ and
a $\ds{\tt\mbox{Lagrange Multiplier}}$ $\ds{4\mu}$:

> \begin{align}
> {\cal F}&\equiv r - 4\mu\braces{\bracks{r\sin\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{\phi}}
> \bracks{r\sin\pars{\theta}\sin\pars{\phi}}
> \bracks{r\cos\pars{\theta}}^{2} -2}
> \\[3mm]&=r-4\mu\bracks{r^{4}\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}\sin\pars{\phi}
> \cos\pars{\phi} - 2}
> \end{align}

$$
{\cal F}=r - \half\,\mu r^{4}\sin^{2}\pars{2\theta}\sin\pars{2\phi} + 8\mu
$$

> $$
> \begin{array}{rclcrcl}
> \partiald{{\cal F}}{r} & = & 0 & \imp & 
> 1 - 2\mu r^{3}\sin^{2}\pars{2\theta}\sin\pars{2\phi} & = & 0
> \\[2mm]
> \partiald{{\cal F}}{\theta} & = & 0 & \imp & 
> -\mu r^{4}\sin\pars{4\theta}\sin\pars{2\phi} & = & 0
> \\[2mm]
> \partiald{{\cal F}}{\phi} & = & 0 & \imp & 
> -\mu r^{4}\sin^{2}\pars{2\theta}\cos\pars{2\phi} & = & 0
> \end{array}
> $$

$\ds{\theta \not\in\braces{0,\pi}}$ and $\ds{\phi \not\in\braces{0,\pi,2\pi}}$. That leads to $\ds{\theta =\phi = {\pi \over 4}}$:
$$
2=xyz^{2}={1 \over 8}\,r^{4}\sin^{2}\pars{\pi \over 2}\sin\pars{\pi \over 2}
={r^{4} \over 8}\ \imp\
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\quad\color{#66f}{\Large r = 2}\quad
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: This is the solution. How did you understand that the Lagrange Multiplier should have a 4 coefficient before starting the solution? Do you know this by experience or it has a rule or a way to understand easier?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent When we start to write the solution we see that there are some 'ugly' fractions around. Then, we go back to the beginning and multiply the Lagrange mult... for a suitable factor to 'kill' those undesired 'ugly' fractions. It doesn't harm.

Comment: I really liked your answer and the way you have typed it. Thank you and wish you all the best. :)

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Thanks a lot. I really enjoy $\displaystyle{\large\LaTeX}$.

Comment: I wish I could be as professional as you in both mathematics and LaTeX. :)

Comment: I had never seen it some in other coordinate systems before. That's a really  nice solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another AM-GM based approach:

$\frac{x^2 + y^2 + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^2}{2}}{4} \ge \sqrt[4]{ \frac{x^2y^2z^4}{4}} = 1$

So the square of the distance is at least $4$, with equality iff $x^2 = y^2 = \frac{z^2}{2} = 1$. Taking signs into account gives you the correct solution set.